Interfaith vs General Culture. Cultural reform
I am at a small secular college, and I believe ground can be covered by allying with chaplains from christian and muslim religions to create a unified discussion about modesty, and create a real impact on the culture of the university.
I'm concerned with the halachic impacts of this, and welcome opinions and wisdom from people more knowledgeable than myself before I run with my intellect and give this a shot.
Theres two subjects I want to cover in this:
1: Modesty in dress as a virtue
2: Marriage and Longevity of relationships as a virtue.
I intend that if such an agreement can be made, to host a discussion that agrees to leave theology and controversy about toeivas off the table, progress could be made in moving a cultural needle to the right, simply by consolidating a voice of agreement
Is this assur? Commendable?

Probably not going to get very far, that's all...

The reality on the ground is that all the christian chaplains expressed assent to this, and also to some extent the head of DEI

You need to find a competent rabbi who knows you and the situation at hand and talk to them. What you're proposing is a planned interfaith effort to proselytize "goodness" to the masses. That's further than Rabbi Soloveichik took his interfaith efforts. (And good luck in today's world having a bunch of men trying to lecture college girls on what they wear...)

Welcome to MiYodeya Shia and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see here for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Christians and Muslims both have a VERY different set of ideas about the topic of modesty and marriage compared to the Torah's picture. It might be about has hard as asking the capitalist society and socialist society to come together to make a program to encourage students to manage their finances better. DEI would also get in the way, because it might eventually get flagged as being exlusionary - some people like being immodest, promiscuous, or polygamous and might claim it is part of their culture. I recommend just doing it as a Jewish Society project

"leave controversy about toeivas off the table" -- I'm so glad nobody is going to be advocating for dishonest business practices!

But backing up -- Rabbi Feinstein was wary of just about any joint efforts with Christian clergy. (He was mildly in favor of nondenominational prayer in public schools, though he understood the concerns against it, and felt it was best for us to stay out of this fight. And despite is "machmir" stance on abortion, he was wary of efforts to have the United States ban it.) Rabbi Soloveichik was pragmatic vis-a-vis his interactions with the Church ... but nothing like what you're describing. (Except for military chaplaincy, which is a whole other ballgame.)

Rabbi Kaii, my hope is to trigger authentic discourse on the subject. the views of modesty have really significant overlap that all exclude what's considered normal on campus.
Those people can come back and advocate for their culture.

Shalom:
at least one of the christian chaplains is a woman. additionally, there are female christian and muslim students on campus (the muslim girl is married) who could potentially be persuaded to help.

Shalom, my core issue is that i'm nervous to do anything against what rav moshe says, and im hoping to better understand rav solevetchik's perspective.
Facts on the ground at my campus is that I'm the only outward jew on campus, there's a pocketful of other people who are jewish, but I'd have significant and better allyship in matters of general morality and promoting it if i teamed up with the other religions.

my creative thought is perhaps if we ritualize as a preface to any interfaith work a short statement of mutual exclusivity and incompatibility of our faith claims, we might be able to go further in having a bedrock to just be people with moral beliefs who can do good work.
The reality is that conservative, ethical people adopt religious faiths, and it's a significant obstacle to building a cultural front when  we cant jump in a room together to promote cultural projects.

@ShiaWinter Capitalists and Socialists also have plenty of overlap about economics. It's the bits that don't overlap that cause all the issues, and it can get quite heated to say the least

a group of capitalists and a group of socialists come across a tribe of cannibals, do they stop the cannibals from eating humans? or is it concerning to them that the capitalists and socialists might blur their boundaries in the process.
